# OData of Outlook Event List cannot order by "Id"

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I tried to get a list of events from Microsoft Graph following [this documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/calendar_list_events).

I would like to get the list with order by `lastModifiedDateTime` and then `id`.

Here is the sample query:

```
var getResource = string.Format("/me/calendar/events/?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge {0}&$orderBy=lastModifiedDateTime, id", XmlConvert.ToString(updatedMin, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc));
```

However, when I executed it, it results an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
    "message": "The property 'Id' does not support filtering.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "bb56a0d0-46f3-4b7c-80bd-043a0b3fd8b5",
      "date": "2018-09-17T15:23:40"
    }
  }
}
```

In fact, I didn't set the `Id` within `$filter`, but instead, I set it as `$orderby`.

When I tried to exclude the `Id` from `$orderby`, it works. Here is the working query:

```
var getResource = string.Format("/me/calendar/events/?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge {0}&$orderBy=lastModifiedDateTime", XmlConvert.ToString(updatedMin, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc));
```

Anyone has an idea on how to order the list based on `Id` as well?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot order by `id`, nor would it make any sense to do so. The `id` is a hashed combination of several properties (subject, path, etc.). As such, their value is neither orderable or human-readable.

This, for example, is an actual `id` value:

```
AAMkAGVmMDEzMTM4LTZmYWUtNDdkNC1hMDZiLTU1OGY5OTZhYmY4OABGAAAAAAAiQ8W967B7TKBjgx9rVEURBwAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAAAAAENAAAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAACNM9xPAAA=
```

Also, I strongly recommend using the [Microsoft Graph .NET Client](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) rather than rolling your own. It will help reduce the learning curve and give you more readable code:

```
await graphClient.Me
   .Calendar
   .Events
   .Request()
   .Filter("lastModifiedDateTime ge {dateTime}")
   .OrderBy("lastModifiedDateTime") 
   .GetAsync();
```

Comment: For some reasons, I have to keep the order of the events. Therefore, ordering it by id will solve it. However, due to the wrong error notification, I assumed there is a bug in the ordering by id. If it isn't a bug. Then at least, they should fix the error notification.

Comment: Ordering it by `id` would do the opposite of what you want, it would result in an almost random order. Also, the order would _change_ if any of those events were edited (even if it was a minor change to the subject). Furthermore, the `/events` endpoint only returns single event and event masters. If there are recurring events, only the first event in the series will be returned. To get the full calendar you need to use `/calendarView`.